# "It goes in and out!"

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is the meaning of the phrase : "It goes in and out!" In the context of someone telling somebody and wants it to be kept as secret.

Comment: It might help if you give a real example of it being used. If you want the information to be secret then I'd expect it to be something more like "It goes in and not out!", i.e. the information goes in (to your head) and doesn't come out.

Comment: I heard it during one of Daredevil's episodes season2, when Frank Castle(Punisher) was about tell Karen(Legal Associate fighting for him) about something which only he knew. he started with the phrase "it goes in and out!", and Karen nodded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably meant to indicate that something goes in one ear and out the other. It implies that it shouldn't tarry in the middle i.e the brain

In the context of a secret, it must mean that the person shouldn't even think of or remember what is being said.

Comment: When we say something 'goes in one ear and out of the other', we mean that the listener does not understand what is said to him or her. It is not usually used in the way you suggest.

Comment: I disagree. It's also used in a prescriptive sense i.e asking someone not to take what's being said to heart, or to disregard what's being said. But I do agree that using it for a secret is a bit of a stretch and not exactly established usage.